# open source smooth particle hydrodynamics

Tags: algorithm, open-source, visualization, simulation, particles

Anyone know of any open source libraries for particle based large scale smooth particle hydrodynamics. I am looking for a easier way of simulating large scale planetary body impacts with rotation.

I was also wondering if you had any ideas on how to visualize the output from said simulation. I have tried using IBM graphviz, but it is very difficult to work with. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How large are we talking here?

If you want *fast* and it is small enough to fit in a few GB, and you have a CUDA GPU, then I would recommend Hoomd-Blue, http://codeblue.umich.edu/hoomd-blue/ . All you need to do is roll your own pairwise potential function. I would modify something simple like the LJ potential.

Although the wiki article has pointers to a few packages: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothed-particle_hydrodynamics#Software

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with a generic platform, I can recommend you use my own project, [GarlicSim](http://garlicsim.org). It'll let you make a visualization as well.

You can ask for help on the mailing list and I'll help you set up a simpack.